# Property of custom JPanel is null during repaint but present during Timer execution

Tags: java, swing, null

This one has me and Gemini both stumped.

The property of Drawing.sceneRootNode evaluates to null or the instance I set depending on whether it's being seen from paint operation or from swing timer that triggers the repaint. (see output below code)

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
  private static JFrame initFrame() {

    //create a new window
    var fr = new JFrame();

    //make it close the program when window exit button is pressed
    fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //get screen size of device
    var ss = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    var sw = ss.width;
    var sh = ss.height;

    //make up a default window size
    var fw = sw / 2;
    var fh = sh / 2;

    //set the window size
    fr.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(fw, fh));

    //center the window in the screen
    fr.setLocation(sw / 2 - fw / 2, sh / 2 - fh / 2);

    //return the frame to whoever called this function
    return fr;
  }

  public static class Drawing extends JPanel {
    public Drawing() {
      super();
    }

    Node sceneRootNode = null;

    public void setSceneRootNode(Node n) {
      this.sceneRootNode = n;
    }
  
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

      System.out.println("[repaint | thread = " + Thread.currentThread() + ", scene root node: " + this.sceneRootNode);

      if (this.sceneRootNode == null) {
        g.drawString("No scene attached to render, Please use <Drawing>.setScene( new Node() )", 0, 10);
        return;
      }

      //get more advanced graphics access
      var ctx = (Graphics2D) g;

      //tell graphics we might paint between pixel offsets ( decimal numbers )
      ctx.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

      //scale the drawing such that 0,0 is top left, and 1,1 is bottom right
//      ctx.scale( (double) this.getWidth(), (double) this.getHeight() );

      this.sceneRootNode.render(ctx);

      //demo rectangle from 0.1, 0.1 to 0.8, 0.8
//      ctx.fill(new Rectangle2D.Double(0.1d,0.1d,0.8d,0.8d));
    }
  }

  public static double getRotation(AffineTransform t) {
    return Math.atan2(t.getShearY(), t.getScaleY());
  }

  public static class Node {
    public AffineTransform localTransform;

    public ArrayList<Node> children;

    public Node() {
      this.children = new ArrayList<>();
      this.localTransform = new AffineTransform();
    }

    public boolean addChild(Node child) {
      return this.children.add(child);
    }

    public boolean removeChild(Node child) {
      return this.children.remove(child);
    }

    public boolean hasChild(Node child) {
      return this.children.contains(child);
    }

    public void render(Graphics2D ctx) {

    }
  }

  //The main method (program start)
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a frame with some opinionated default settings
    var fr = initFrame();

    var d = new Drawing();
    //Add our custom drawing class as a new component in the window
    fr.getContentPane().add(
      new Drawing(),
      BorderLayout.CENTER
    );

    //show the frame on screen
    fr.setVisible(true);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
      var scene = new Node() {
        @Override
        public void render(Graphics2D ctx) {
          ctx.drawString("Hello Scene", 0f, 10f);
        }
      };

      System.out.println("[init | thread = " + Thread.currentThread() + ", scene root node will be: " + scene);

      d.setSceneRootNode(scene);
    });

    Timer t = new Timer(1000 / 15, (action) -> {
      fr.repaint();
      System.out.println("[timer | thread = " + Thread.currentThread() + ", scene root node: " + d.sceneRootNode);
    });
    t.setRepeats(true);
    t.start();
  }
}
```

```
[init | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node will be: Main$1@5f97a380
[repaint | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: null
[timer | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: Main$1@5f97a380
[repaint | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: null
[timer | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: Main$1@5f97a380
[repaint | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: null
[timer | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: Main$1@5f97a380
[repaint | thread = Thread[#24,AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main], scene root node: null
```

Any ideas? I feel like this will either be super simple, or I will learn some arcane knowledge of swing.

Comment: 1)  All Swing components should be created on the EDT. 2) the setSceneRootNode() method should invoke `repaint()` to make sure the components gets repainted. 3) However, the main problem is that you create 2 instances of the `Drawing` class. Code should be: `fr.getContentPane().add(d, BorderLayout.CENTER`

Comment: Ah, simple mistake got me! Thank you so much